# Loop v-for through components taken from data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to use `v-for` to render list of components from the list I have in data.

This is my code

```
<template>
    <ticket-panel/>
    <user-panel/>
    <map-panel/>
    <info-panel/>
    <product-panel/>
</template>
```

I want to do something like this

```
<template v-for="component in components" :key="name">
??? <component> ???
</template>


data: function() {
return {
components: [
    { name: "ticket-panel" },
    { name: "user-panel" },
    { name: "map-panel" },
    { name: "info-panel" },
    { name: "product-panel" }
]
}
}
```

How to write `<template>` or `<componentName>` so it renders properly? I used Google a lot but I did not find any close answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like following snippet, with special attribute [`:is`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#slot)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      components: [{name: "ticket-panel"}, {name: "user-panel"}, {name: "map-panel"}, {name: "info-panel"}, {name: "product-panel"}]
    };
  },
})
app.component('ticket-panel', {
  template: `<div>ticket-panel</div>`
})
app.component('user-panel', {
  template: `<div>user-panel</div>`
})
app.component('map-panel', {
  template: `<div>map-panel</div>`
})
app.component('info-panel', {
  template: `<div>info-panel</div>`
})
app.component('product-panel', {
  template: `<div>product-panel</div>`
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="component in components" :key="component.name">
    <component :is="component.name"></component> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I reproduced this solution in my project with components in separated files and it works great. The ```:is``` helped a lot. Thank you

Comment: @Robert Veselý you are welcome mate, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this process, hopefully, it will work for you. Here is an example for you:

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```